# How to ensure that readyState of a WebSocket has turned to CLOSED (3)?

Tags: javascript, websocket

Let's suppose there is a websocket created as following:

```
var ws = new WebSocket(url);
```

Also, assume communication via this web socket works fine too.

It has been found that closing this WebSocket using following, sets its readyState to **CLOSING (2)** but it never gets to readyState **CLOSED (3)**.

```
ws.close();
```

**Question:**
- When this happens onmessage event, keeps on hitting as the WebSocket connection is not closed yet. How can its closed state can be ensured so that onmessage stops hitting?

WebSocket readState read: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WebSocket

Comment: Have you encountered this behaviour? I cannot confirm that "*onmessage event keeps on hitting as the WebSocket connection is not closed yet*"

Comment: Yes. I am encountering this issue. WebSocket connection is in state "Closing". I am not sure how it goes to "Closed" from "Closing".

Comment: Does this happen in all browsers? What exactly do you need this for? Quick fix: add `if (this.readyState!=1) return;` to your onmessage handler.

Answer (score 1):

> onmessage event keeps on hitting as the WebSocket connection is not closed yet.

That must not happen. From [the spec](http://www.w3.org/TR/websockets/#feedback-from-the-protocol):

> *When a WebSocket message has been received […], [and] If the `readyState` attribute's value is not `OPEN`, then abort [any further] steps.*

If your socket's readystate is already `CLOSING`, it will no more emit any `message` events.

> readyState is set to `CLOSING` but it never gets to `CLOSED`

That implies to me that the [connection is not properly closed](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6455#section-7). Especially, this scenario seems to happen when the closing handshake has been started, but the server does not respond with a close control frame.